# How can I get the location and width of window buttons/window icon?

Tags: java, awt

The windows explorer has a really cool graphical feature, I think, those buttons on the window decoration look really cool. I know this is not really possible in java, but I think its definetely worth a try, so I made a little workaround/hack solution that can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/G69qEAXv). But I ran into a problem: I don't know how to get the distance between the border and the location I can place the buttons on without hiding anything. Is there a way to get that value platform-independently? (I want to get at least the right padding) This is what I want:
[image]
for ubuntu I would want to have the right padding be 0, and the left padding as shown:
[image]
Thanks for your patience.
**EDIT:** This is what I've already got, the left padding is equal to the top border s height and the right padding is hardcoded to 138 pixels. Not really platform-independent.
[image]
All I have to do is remove the decoration of the second window and add some buttons to it.
**EDIT:** I want to use the Platform-LAF.

Comment: I doubt that there is a platform-independent solution.

Comment: I doubt it too,  but I think its definetely worth the 100 rep.

Comment: Have you tried using the JInternalFrame LAF to paint the frame border manually?

Comment: I want to use the platform-LAF, sorry. But thanks for your help, much appreciated :)

Comment: @JimmyT. If you got a good-looking LAF I can do that with that would be cool (I would actually give you the 100 rep) but in my experience every LAF in java looks ugly (except for the platform LAF). Better that than nothing :)

Comment: javaFX could really be handy here

Comment: @Elltz could you provide a good-looking example? Everything I archieved with JavaFX looks worse than this car: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Fiat_Multipla_front_20080825.jpg/1280px-Fiat_Multipla_front_20080825.jpg

Comment: lo, ok, can you go over, put me to speed exactly what you want, like you are my client, :).lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. It is definitely not possible in Platform-LAF (although it is possible in Metal).

Also, you *shouldn't* do this. See for example the [Windows UX Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742501.aspx):

> Don't add controls to a window frame. Put the controls within the window instead.

So, there is a good reason this is not possible :)

Comment: Adding the controls on a JToolBar on the content pane looks really weird. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nbjCgQ5hsTVGw4b2xFcDFBZTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is with the platform LAF. Would be cool if you had a good-looking platform-independent alternative solution